# Forcing namespace reload using Clojure core.typed

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojure-core.typed

There may be something I really don't understand about core.typed and the way you need to call check-ns.

Here's what's working and then what's not working:

- `lein new default showso`
- Lauching Emacs
- add the `[org.clojure/core.typed "0.2.34"]` dependency to *project.clj*
- modify *core.clj* so that it contains:

  ```
  (ns showso.core
    :require [clojure.core.typed :refer [ann check-ns AnyInteger]]))

  (ann somevar Number)
  (def somevar 42)
  ```
- cider-jack-in
- REPL> (ns showso.core)
- cider-eval-buffer
- showsho.core> (check-ns)

  ```
  Initializing core.typed ...
  "Elapsed time: 2537.589357 msecs"
  core.typed initialized.
  Start collecting showso.core
  Finished collecting showso.core
  Collected 1 namespaces in 2595.464317 msecs
  Start checking showso.core
  Checked showso.core in 20.24605 msecs
  Checked 1 namespaces (approx. 5 lines) in 2619.38047 msecs
  :ok
  ```

So so far so good, everything is working fine.

Now what I really don't get at all is that if a modify the `(def somevar 42)`, which must be a `Number`, to, say, a `String`, then I simply cannot find a way to have the `check-ns` function take that change into account:

```
(def somevar "bugsme")
```

Now, no matter what I try: cider-eval-buffer, cider-eval-last-expression, redefining `somevar` directly from the repl, etc. apparently nothing I do makes `check-ns` take the changes into account.

It's as if the results from the last check-ns was cached somewhere and never re-running.

Even if I kill all the cider Emacs buffers and relaunch cider-jack-in, the changes are still not taking into account. check-ns keeps telling me everything is ok.

The only way I can have check-ns take the change into account is to entirely close Emacs and relaunch it.

Note that it's exactly the same if I first test with a bogus value: then check-ns correctly finds the type mismatch (*"Expected: java.lang.Number"*...) but then if I fix it there's no way besides relaunching Emacs to have `check-ns` report no error.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some caching of previous values going on?

Is there an easy way to "force" check-ns to take the changes into account, directly from Emacs, without having to launch a new REPL (not even sufficient in my case) / relaunching Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save the file before each call to `check-ns`.